# Aggregate rows close in time

Tags: r, performance, datetime, data.table, aggregate

I have a data set in R with the following format:

```
data = data.table(
id = c(1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3 ,3, 3),
Start = c("2019-03-01 09:15:36", 
"2019-01-01 08:00:00", "2019-01-01 08:00:10","2019-01-01 08:00:30",
"2019-01-01 08:00:30", "2019-01-01 08:00:40","2019-01-01 08:00:50",
"2019-01-01 08:01:10", "2019-01-01 08:01:20","2019-01-01 08:01:31"
))
data$Start = as.POSIXct(data$Start ,format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

each row represents an interaction with a person, with each person identified by the id (In the example data set I have 3 people). By definition, interactions with less than 15s between their start date should be merged (count only as one). This 15s window should extend with each new interaction (see the result of the example for person 3).

Given this rule, and for `data`, I want to create a newID column that identify the unique interaction. The results should be:

```
data$newID 
[1] 1 2 2 3 4 4 4 5 5 5
```

This fells like something with should be possible within `data.table`, without inefficient `for` loops, but I can´t make it work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by @Sotos answer, I think the right solution is:

```
data$test = c(T,data$ID[-1] != data$ID[-nrow(data)] |
                           diff.difftime(data$Start) > 15)
```

This generate a Boolean where all the `F` should be removed (although this does not create a new ID, as per the question, it solved the implicit removal problem).

Comment: something like `data[, newID := cumsum(id != shift(id, fill=id[1L]) | c(TRUE, diff(Start) > 15L))]`

Comment: @chinsoon12 yes, that would answer the initial question.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to calculate the difference and change group every time a value is greater than 15

```
data[, new := c(NA,diff.difftime(Start))][, new_id := cumsum(c(1, abs(na.omit(new)) >= 15))]
```

which gives,

> ```
>     id               Start      new new_id
>  1:  1 2019-03-01 09:15:36       NA      1
>  2:  2 2019-01-01 08:00:00 -5102136      2
>  3:  2 2019-01-01 08:00:10       10      2
>  4:  2 2019-01-01 08:00:30       20      3
>  5:  3 2019-01-01 08:00:00      -30      4
>  6:  3 2019-01-01 08:00:10       10      4
>  7:  3 2019-01-01 08:00:20       10      4
>  8:  3 2019-01-01 08:00:40       20      5
>  9:  3 2019-01-01 08:00:50       10      5
> 10:  3 2019-01-01 08:01:01       11      5
> ```

You can drop any unwanted columns as per usual

Comment: It worked for the example, but it will fail if the next person has a start time close to the last of the previous person. I changed the example to reflect this situation

Answer (score 0):

I am curious if following would work for your data:

```
library(data.table)

dt[
  ,
  session := frollapply(Start, 2, function(x) diff(x) >= 15, fill = 1),
  by = 'id'
][
  ,
  session := cumsum(session)
]

#     id               Start session
#  1:  1 2019-03-01 09:15:36       1
#  2:  2 2019-01-01 08:00:00       2
#  3:  2 2019-01-01 08:00:10       2
#  4:  2 2019-01-01 08:00:30       3
#  5:  3 2019-01-01 08:00:00       4
#  6:  3 2019-01-01 08:00:10       4
#  7:  3 2019-01-01 08:00:20       4
#  8:  3 2019-01-01 08:00:40       5
#  9:  3 2019-01-01 08:00:50       5
# 10:  3 2019-01-01 08:01:01       5
```

Data:

```
dt = data.table(
  id = c(1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3 , 3, 3),
  Start = as.POSIXct(
    c(
      "2019-03-01 09:15:36",
      "2019-01-01 08:00:00",
      "2019-01-01 08:00:10",
      "2019-01-01 08:00:30",
      "2019-01-01 08:00:00",
      "2019-01-01 08:00:10",
      "2019-01-01 08:00:20",
      "2019-01-01 08:00:40",
      "2019-01-01 08:00:50",
      "2019-01-01 08:01:01"
    ),
    ,
    format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
  )
)
```

Comment: I can't test it now, but can you try with the updated data (although I think that by having a ````by = id`` your answer won't fall into the same issue as Sotos's. It would be interesting to benchmark it again my answer in a data set with 10.000.000 rows

Comment: @DiogoSantos Seems to work fine with updated data. However I don't know how would it perform on 10,000,000  rows - might be slow, that's a lot of data. Anyway, let me know how it ends up.